# When I try to open a specific folder, only open a recent folder

Tags: android, directory

I have a problem when I try to open a specific folder, I have this code to open my folder `/myprojects/test1`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myProjects/test1");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

That code only open me a recent folder, where I can see all my photos in my gallery and don't open the specific folder

I'm testing with API 26

[image]

Comment: does this /myProjects/test1 directory even exist on your phone?

Comment: Yes and I have files in the folder (Images)

Answer (score 0):

You should update the following line

```
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
```

with

```
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");
```