# How to open a specific folder when using a file picker?

Tags: java, android

I use an Image picker in my android app but cannot open a specific folder. Whenever I open the selector using the intent, it opens the recently opened folder. I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54085325/when-i-try-to-open-a-specific-folder-only-open-a-recent-folder) post, but it does not work for me. This is what I tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: "I use an Image picker in my android app" -- `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not really an image picker. "but cannot open a specific folder" -- correct, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not offer this. There are [dozens of image picker libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157?sort=created). Perhaps one of them has a feature set that meets your needs.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, @CommonsWare, but it took me a while looking in those libraries. I couldn't find anything that does that task :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I discovered this wasn't possible. So, instead, I had to get all the files in a directory and display them in a recycler view.

Comment: Is this still the case? Can someone who used it make sure?